# Unable to use Web API OData v3 feed in Excel

Tags: excel, odata

I have a self-hosted Web API OData v3 service:

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");
            config.MapODataServiceRoute(
            routeName: "ODataRoute",
            routePrefix: null,
            model: builder.GetEdmModel());

            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }
    }
```

I also have the following Controller, which exposes a full CRUD:

```
public class ProductsController : ODataController
    {
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        private bool ProductExists(int key)
        {
            return db.Products.Any(p => p.Id == key);
        }
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        [EnableQuery]
        public IQueryable<Product> Get()
        {
            return db.Products;
        }
        [EnableQuery]
        public SingleResult<Product> Get([FromODataUri] int key)
        {
            IQueryable<Product> result = db.Products.Where(p => p.Id == key);
            return SingleResult.Create(result);
        }

        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Product product)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            db.Products.Add(product);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Created(product);
        }

        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Patch([FromODataUri] int key, Delta<Product> product)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            var entity = await db.Products.FindAsync(key);
            if (entity == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            product.Patch(entity);
            try
            {
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!ProductExists(key))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return Updated(entity);
        }

        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put([FromODataUri] int key, Product update)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            if (key != update.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            db.Entry(update).State = EntityState.Modified;
            try
            {
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!ProductExists(key))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return Updated(update);
        }

        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete([FromODataUri] int key)
        {
            var product = await db.Products.FindAsync(key);
            if (product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            db.Products.Remove(product);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }
    }
```

I am able to access this feed from a browser without any issues.

However, when I try to get Excel 2013 to use this data feed (using this url:  http://localhost:8080/Products), I get this error:

"We can't use the data from this feed. Make sure the external data feed server is available and your connection information is correct"

What can I do to make Excel 2013 to work with this data feed?

Comment: I have the same problem.  Would love to know a possible solution